# Cannot install Ubuntu or another Linux OS!

Tags: system-installation

Hello I got a new gaming Computer without OS so I tried to install Xubuntu!

It failed with the Error message: "Couldn't execute Gnu grub Install at 
**/dev/sdf**
This is a fatal error!"

My uncle said It must be the install disk so I tried to install the "Normal" Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from a disk... It gave me the same Error message except of the file path

... gnu grub install at **/dev/sda** ...

I only got one hard drive with 1 Terabyte space Why is the file path different I only got 1 hard drive...
Also while booting the live CD I got instantly before the loading bar appears  error messages

```
Couldn't mount /dev/sda No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sdb No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sdc No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sdd No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sde No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sdf No medium found
Couldn't mount /dev/sdg No medium found
```

I just don't know how I could install Ubuntu without a clue why it can't execute gnu grub install.

And I'm wondering why it shows at Xubuntu a different file path then in Ubuntu I got only 1 hard drive.

Edit: now I finished the installation without any errors cause I found out how to avoid this error but I get when the computer boots the error message unknown Filesystem and it boots into grub rescue

Comment: May you open terminal (while in the liveCD), and issue the command: "sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
"?

Comment: What is the effect of this command and should I enter it before or after I try to install?

Comment: And what should I paste into NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE, and the other parameters

Comment: It lists the name, filesystem type, size, mountpoint, and label of each drive mounted onto your system. And no, please don't replace the params with anything else.

Comment: And do it while in the live session.